# Another tool like Ireport (JasperReport) that support ejbql connections

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0, jasper-reports

i'm been using ireport (jasperReport) for a lot of time, and everything goes fine until i begin to use ejbql connection, for this type of connection the ireport was not the best tool, And i Wanna know if there are another tool for reports based in java technology like ireport and also opensource. Thanks

Comment: http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting .. some alternatives

Comment: Yes, i want to use JPQL queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Business Intelligence and Reporting Tools ([BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/)) Eclipse project is definitely the way to Go, I've been using it for about two years now with no complain.

- Eclipse plugin Report Designer  (Very, very, easy to use).
- Multiple report output formats.
- You can embedded the BIRT report engine runtime with you app, or call it via a http request.
- Has a very active user community.
- Has lots of charts and components.
- Can be extended.

For more reporting options take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243326/generating-reports-what-works-for-you).